# Django allauth LinkedIn API not returning full profile data

Tags: django, authentication, oauth, linkedin-api, django-allauth

I have a an app with which I'm experimenting with Django Allauth, specifically the LinkedIn api.

I am defining the scope in my settings like so:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = \
{
    'linkedin':
    {
        'SCOPE': ['r_fullprofile', 'r_emailaddress']
    }
}
```

And I am outputting this info to a template using:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load auth_extras %}
{% load account %}
{% load socialaccount %}

{% block content %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}

{% for key, value in user.socialaccount_set.all.0.extra_data.items %}
<ul>
    <li>{{ key }}: {{ value }}</li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

When I authorize an account through LinkedIn I can see it is asking for a approval for basic profile, email address and full profile. But The `user.socialaccount_set.all.0.extra_data` object only has the basic profile and email adress data. What happened to the full profile data?

Additionally, is `user.socialaccount_set.all.0.extra_data` really the best way to get access to the all the data exposed by a provider?

Answer (score 3):

I recently faced this issue and came across this: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/397.

Short Answer: It seems if we define extra PROFILE_FIELDS in settings.py, those fields are copied to extra_data.

So for completeness here is my settings.py (which includes both facebook and linkedin)

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = \
    {'facebook': {'SCOPE': ['email', 'user_about_me', 'user_birthday',
                            'user_education_history','user_work_history',
                            'user_hometown',
                            'user_location',
                            'user_religion_politics','user_subscriptions',
                            'read_stream',
                            'read_insights',
                            'read_friendlists',
                            'user_likes',
                            'user_interests',
                            'user_groups'
                            ],
                  'AUTH_PARAMS': {},
                  'METHOD': 'oauth2'
                },

     'linkedin': {'SCOPE': ['r_emailaddress', 'r_fullprofile', 'r_emailaddress', 'r_contactinfo', 'r_network'],
                  'PROFILE_FIELDS': ['id', 'first-name',
                              'last-name',
                              'email-address',
                              'picture-url',
                              'public-profile-url', 'skills', 'headline'
                  ]
     }
    }
```

And I can print skills and headline using:

```
@receiver(user_logged_in)
def populate_profile_login2(request, **kwargs):
{
    try:
        extra_data = kwargs.get('user').socialaccount_set.filter(provider='linkedin')[0].extra_data
        for key, value in extra_data.iteritems():
            print key, value
    except:
        print ' NOT LINKEDIN'


 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using the new linkedin_oauth2 and ran into the same issue.
Took me a little while to figure out my mistake, I was using the wrong provider name ( 'linkedin' instead of 'linkedin_oauth2' )

hope this will help someone else in the future.

This (settings.py) configuration works as expected.

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = \
        'linkedin_oauth2': {'SCOPE': ['r_fullprofile', 'r_emailaddress'],
                  'PROFILE_FIELDS': ['id', 'first-name',
                              'last-name',
                              'email-address',
                              'picture-url',
                              'public-profile-url',
                              'skills', 'headline']}
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my linkedin configuration (settings.py) it works with:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = \
{
'linkedin': 
    {'SCOPE': [ 'r_emailaddress',
                'r_fullprofile',
                'r_emailaddress',
                'r_contactinfo',
                'r_network'],
      'PROFILE_FIELDS':
            [
                'id',
                'first-name',
                'last-name',

                'email-address',
                'picture-url',
                'public-profile-url',
                'skills',

                'headline',
                'industry',

                'num-connections',
                'positions',
                'interests',
                'languages',
                'certifications',
                'educations',
                'courses',
                'three-current-positions',
                'three-past-positions',
                'recommendations-received',
                'honors-awards'
            ]
    }
}
```

All the fields are defined in:
http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields

You must ensure that you are in the scope "r_fullprofile" to obtain all the data mentioned above.

I'm working with:
django-allauth==0.14.2
and 
Django==1.5.1

I hope that helps!